# Multilingual App Toolkit Add Only Strings inside of .xlf File for Translation

Tags: c#, winforms, multilingual-app-toolkit

I enabled Multilingual App Toolkit 4.0 for my WinForms C# project. After that I added a language for translation which created a .xlf File for that language. However when I open that file Multilingual App Toolkit 4.0 Editor it shows too many things like image files screen dimensions etc. I just want to translate string.
[image]

How to exclude other resourse from .xlf file?

Comment: To work around this issue, I simply wrote a script (actually an unit test) that marks all these elements as "non translatable"

Comment: Technically though, this is correct: You might need to adjust the size of elements in a dialog box for a different language (e.g. in most cases, the german translation will be longer than the english text)

Comment: @PMF Yes you are right about different sizes however It makes translators life hard. I can adjust sizes after getting translations.

Comment: Open the .xlt file in the editor. Order the list by the Automatic Translator Indicator (the resources with a `Translatable` auto-status = Yes first) select all the other entries and set the state to Final` instead of Needs Review. Save the file (make a backup of the original) -- Back to Visual Studio, right click a .xlt file in `MultilingualResources` and select `Multimedia Toolkit -> Export Translations`. In the `Include` filter, keep only `Needs review` selected. You should see that only a small subset of entries remains. The exported file contains only stuff to translate / review

Comment: When a translation / review is completed, use the `Import / Recycle translations...` tool. Select the reviewed file and use the `Import & Recycle` Button to import the file into the existing (extended) file. The tool replaces only the entries found in the imported file, the others are preserved -- The automatic translation tool (Azure) usually does a good job if you follow the general instructions on how to create translatable content (of course each language has its nuances, but there's a good database for these, too)